# Distributed computing for multiplying numbers

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

Can you show me how I can multiply two integers which are M bits long using at most O(N^1.63) processors in O(N) parallel time in python.
I think that karatsuba algorithm would work but I don't understand how can I implement it parallely.

Comment: I don't see how this question is answerable without more detail about your specific application.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It is parallel karatsuba algorithm.